# ASP.Net vNext structure and development flow

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2015

I've recently downloaded VS15 CTP-6 to get the feeling of how to develop the next generation VS projects, but having trouble figuring out the development flow I should be following with this separation of code and wwwroot.

The way I understand it is this (Angular project):

1. Develop views, css and js.
2. Use grunt tasks to uglify and copy css and js to wwwroot folder.
3. Browse wwwroot as a local IIS site to see the changes.
4. When wwwroot is ready for production, copy its content.

But if I find a problem during step 3, how can I find its origin given that the js and css are minified ?

Surely I'm wrong, so should I create another copy of wwwroot for development, without the minification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use grunt task to uglify/minify your code when you're ready to go in production
And use an other grunt task to copy your code when you're in dev
Or you can use uglify with 2 target: 1 to uglify and 1 to beautify:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        bower: {
            install: {
                options: {
                    targetDir: "wwwroot/lib",
                    layout: "byComponent",
                    cleanTargetDir: false
                }
            }
        },
        uglify: {
            ugli_target: {
                files: {
                    "wwwroot/scripts/chat.js": ["Scripts/chat.js"]
                }
            },
            beauty_target: {
                options: {
                    beautify: {
                        beautify: true
                    },
                    mangle: false,
                    sourceMap: true
                },
                files: {
                    "wwwroot/scripts/chat.js": ["Scripts/chat.js"]
            }
        }
        }
    });

    // This command registers the default task which will install bower packages into wwwroot/lib
    grunt.registerTask("default", ["bower:install"]);

    // The following line loads the grunt plugins.
    // This line needs to be at the end of this this file.
    grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-contrib-uglify");
    grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-bower-task");
};
```